# Jolt transform convert large array to smaller array

Tags: transformation, jolt

My input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "label": [
      {
        "name": "abc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": [
      {
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My spec:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "label": {
        "0": {
          "name": "name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
 "name": "abc"
}, {
  "name": "xyz"
}]
```

Generated output:

```
{
  "name" : [ "abc", "xyz" ]
}
```

How do I not combine the array in the spec?

Answer (score 0):

Try this spec,

```
[
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "*": {
         "label": {
           "*": {
             "name": "[&3].name"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ]
```